# issue installing active admin - rails 3.0.3 - uninitialized constant Formtastic::SemanticFormHelper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activeadmin

I'm trying to add activeadmin to my rails 3.0.3 app.

I'm following the instructions [here](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin)

When I run - rake db:migrate  I get the following error -

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Formtastic::SemanticFormHelper
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.2.2/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:167:in `eval'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.2.2/lib/active_admin/resource_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.2.2/lib/active_admin/dashboards/dashboard_controller.rb:3:in `<module:Dashboards>'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.2.2/lib/active_admin/dashboards/dashboard_controller.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveAdmin>'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.2.2/lib/active_admin/dashboards/dashboard_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
(eval):1:in `generate_dashboard_controller'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.2.2/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:167:in `eval'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.2.2/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:167:in `generate_dashboard_controller'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.2.2/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:38:in `initialize'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.2.2/lib/active_admin.rb:147:in `new'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.2.2/lib/active_admin.rb:147:in `find_or_create_namespace'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.2.2/lib/active_admin.rb:282:in `load_default_namespace'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.2.2/lib/active_admin.rb:188:in `load!'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.2.2/lib/active_admin.rb:212:in `routes'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the `formtastic` gem. In the current version of active-admin (0.3.2) it is correctly specified as a dependency.

So I hope updating the activeadmin gem (`bundle update activeadmin`) will fix it.

If that does not fix it, I would add `formtastic` explicitly to the `Gemfile`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In rails 3 the Formtastic::SemanticFormHelper became => **Formtastic::Helpers::FormHelper**

Don't forget to load your lib. By default rails don't load them so you can just uncomment **config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)** in your application.rb